# I need VB6 Code Combobox

Tags: vb6

I need code for VB6, ComboBox if I change itemlist1 to itemlist2 automatic transfer to list 2 example

[image]

[image]

```
combo1.listindex
01 item list 1 
02 item list 2
```

..etc

```
itemlist1
Apple
Orange

itemlist2
Book
CD desk
```

Comment: not clear of what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

Hope I got this right. The combo1 contains "Item list 1" and "item list 2". If I select "Item list 1" then "Apple, Orange" are populated in combo2 and if I select "Item list 2" then "Book, CD desk" are populated in combo2. Below is the code.

```
Private listItem1() As String
Private listItem2() As String

Private Sub Combo1_Click()
    Dim intCount As Integer
    Combo2.Clear
    If Combo1.ListIndex = 0 Then
         For intCount = LBound(listItem1) To UBound(listItem1) - 1
            Combo2.AddItem listItem1(intCount), intCount
         Next intCount
    ElseIf Combo1.ListIndex = 1 Then
         For intCount = LBound(listItem2) To UBound(listItem2) - 1
            Combo2.AddItem listItem2(intCount), intCount
         Next intCount
    End If
    Combo2.ListIndex = 0
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()

    Combo1.AddItem "Item list 1", 0
    Combo1.AddItem "Item List 2", 1

    ReDim listItem1(2)
    ReDim listItem2(2)
    listItem1(0) = "Apple"
    listItem1(1) = "Orange"
    listItem2(0) = "Book"
    listItem2(1) = "CD Desk"

    Combo1.ListIndex = 0

End Sub
```

Comment: You are a champ for event attempting to answer this question. You get +1

Comment: Thanks a lot, can you make it to source, that will be more easy for me because i'm beginner :p

Comment: It's a good answer to your question (+1ed), it already is source that you can just copy and paste.  One thing I'd change is to use  ReDim listItem1(0 To 1) and then drop the -1 from the Ubound.